# how to edit clistview and cgridview with bootstrap3

Tags: php, yii, twitter-bootstrap-3

I like to use bootstrap 3 with yii. I am stuck with how to edit CListview and CGridview and add in the neccesarry classes.

My code

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView',array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,

// refers to the partial view named '_thumb'
'itemView'=>'_thumb',  

'template' => "{summary}{sorter}{pager}{items}{pager}",
'itemsCssClass' => 'nav row',

'pagerCssClass'=>'pagination', // doesn't work is set on <div> instead of <ul>

// 'sorterCssClass'=>'row-fluid', // how to so this...

)); ?>
```

I tried putting the 'pagination' class. but the class is splaced on the **div** tag instead of the **ul** tag that is required. With CGridview it is the same

I used the yii bootstrap extension but it doesn't work with bootstrap3 and I like to know how to do it the easy way.

Comment: You might look at Yii-Booster, it works with Bootstrap 3 - http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/extendedGridView

Comment: thank you I will look at it. I didn't knew it was compatible with b3 yet. I wish it would be easier in Yii to just change a view  html and css tags.